# How to identify a unidentified PSK wifi encryption

Tags: wifi, airodump-ng, psk

I have an unidentified PSK encryption in airodump's output (see red square on screenshot) and I would like to get more information about the encryption method used by the network: do you know any tool that would give me more information about the encryption type?

***Note:*** *I'm not trying here to break the encryption method, I just want to get more information about it.*

My question is more about the fact that it does not mention "WPA[2]": why? Why is the `ENC` field empty?

[image: Airodump output]

Comment: It literally tells you what encryption method is used under "cipher". Google CCMP.

Comment: Sorry, my question was maybe not clear : I meant why I don't have a "WPA" mention on it ? Why this one is so special that I don't have information on it ?

Comment: If no ENC is shown, it means it hasn't gather enough data. as in the documentations says: "(Not enough data to choose between WEP and WPA2)" so... it knows it has CCMP which means it **might** be WPA2 as it generally is. and TKIP for WPA. (WPA3 it's not that widespread yet, so as of today we can assume it is not)

Comment: Even if I let airodump running in background for a while, or if I deauth client, it does not "update" the ENC column : do you know if there is a way to precisely identify if it is WPA or WPA2 ?

Comment: @JohnKravicz yes, save the captured packets to a file, and see if Wireshark or another tool can report more information.